# HandbrakeCLI bash batch script only transcodes one file and exits

Tags: bash, handbrake

Iam writing a bash script that loops through webm files and transcodes them to .mp4 using HandbrakeCLI. However, to my surprise, Handbrake only transcodes one file instead of all of them. Here's my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

trxcode(){
    fp=$1
    new_fp=$2
    HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$fp" -o "$new_fp"
}

find ~/Videos/zik_vids/ -iname "*.webm" -type f | while read fp; do 
    fd=$(dirname "${fp}") 
    fn=$(basename "${fp}")
    f="${fn%.*}"; new_fp="${fd}/${f}.mp4"
    trxcode "$fp" "$new_fp"
done
```

Handbrake says "
Encode done!

HandBrake has exited."

Comment: The only thing I see wrong is the assignments in `trxcode()`: these should be quoted (`fp="$1"; new_fp="$2"`); they will fail if there are spaces in either file path.

Comment: I've run the script again, it just exits after the first encode job is done. It doesn't continue with the loop

Comment: What happens if you put `echo ` in front of the `HandBrakeCLI` call? Do you get more than one command listed? What about putting it in front of the `trxcode` call? Does this make a difference?

Comment: Actually echoing an empty string and piping it to handbrake like  echo "" | HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$fp" -o "$new_fp" solves the issue. I've read that it's something to do with Handbrake and the while loop conflicting in standard input. I don't really understand, but it solves my issue now.

Comment: OK. Without knowing what Handbrake does, I would never have guessed that it reads from standard input when a `-i` parameter is given. If you want to avoid using standard input altogether, you can put the handling for each file into a script (eg `CallHB`) and use `find ... -exec CallHB {} \;`. I usually prefer this way of processing `find` output, rather than piping to `while read ...`, though there are some instances when the latter can be preferable.